# Flowplayer not working in FireFox

Tags: flowplayer

Seems a bit weird but flowplayer works awesome in chrome and Doesnt work properly on FireFox.

My setup is [here](http://bratie.com:8080/affiliate/aqrsport) .

Can anyone share some thoughts?

on FF The video is actually playing in background of the splash image, but not visible

Answer (score 1):

Problem Resolved:

Seems like [FullPage](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) plugin by Alvaro Trigo conflicting with the Flowplayer